# Facebook FQL PHP query example to lists Facebook page posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am very new to FQL & I was hoping someone could show me a working example of PHP code used to query using Facebook FQL to list a Facebook pages posts?

Sorry, I am searching without much luck here, I can find the FQL, but I can't figure out how to use it with PHP

A code sample would be really great.

Comment: Why dont you want to get them using the Graph API? Is FQL necessary?

Comment: Maybe not... actually I found this: 

$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/pageid/feed?limit=1');

which works exactly as needed

now my only question is, since this lists all posts, what if i wanted to lookup one specific post by it's ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the posts from a page-

```
SELECT message,description FROM stream WHERE source_id={page-id}
```

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20message%2Cdescription%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3D%27290805814352519%27)

Check the list of fields [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).

---

> how to use fql with PHP

Here's how you should use this with PHP-

```
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => {query}
);

$result = $facebook->api($params);
print_r($result);
```